# How to use xdebug with sublime to debug python script

Tags: python, xdebug, sublimetext, sublimetext3

Trying to move to sublime from heavier IDEs. The thing I noticed it lacked was debugging compared to the intellij IDEs. Through research I learned about XDebug and I believe it can provide comparable debugging. However, I'm having trouble setting it up.

Here is what I've done:

1. Installed sublime 3
2. Installed package manager
3. Used package manager to install XDebug
4. Noticed files were missing so I deleted the package through the package manager
5. Cloned the repo from martomo (https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug)
6. Placed it in my Packaged folder
   [image]
7. Then I went to XDebug.sublime-settings and I'm not sure how to configure it (what am I linking to, what url does it need, etc...)

   ```js
   {
       // For remote debugging to resolve the file locations
       // it is required to configure the path mapping
       // with the server path as key and local path as value.
       //
       // Make sure to use absolute path when defining server path,
       // because Xdebug debugger engine does not return symbolic links.
       //
       // Example:
       // "/absolute/path/to/file/on/server" : "/path/to/file/on/computer",
       // "/var/www/htdocs/example/" : "C:/git/websites/example/"
       "path_mapping": {

       },

       // Determine which URL to launch in the default web browser
       // when starting/stopping a session.
       "url": "",

       // An IDE key is used to identify with debugger engine
       // when Sublime Text will start or stop a debugging session.
       //
       // This package does not filter sessions by IDE key,
       // it will accept any IDE key, also ones that do not match this configured IDE key.
       // It is merely used when launching the default web browser with the configured URL.
       "ide_key": "sublime.xdebug",

       // Which port number Sublime Text should listen
       // to connect with debugger engine.
       "port": 9000,

       // Show super globals in context view.
       "super_globals": true,

       // Maximum amount of array children
       // and object's properties to return.
       "max_children": 32,

       // Maximum amount of
       // variable data to initially retrieve.
       "max_data": 1024,

       // Maximum amount of nested levels to retrieve
       // of array elements and object properties.
       "max_depth": 1,

       // Break at first line on session start, when debugger engine has connected.
       "break_on_start": false,

       // Break on exceptions, suspend execution
       // when the exception name matches an entry in this list value.
       "break_on_exception": [
           // E_ERROR, E_CORE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_USER_ERROR
           "Fatal error",
           // E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR (since PHP 5.2.0)
           "Catchable fatal error",
           // E_WARNING, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_WARNING, E_USER_WARNING
           "Warning",
           // E_PARSE
           "Parse error",
           // E_NOTICE, E_USER_NOTICE
           "Notice",
           // E_STRICT
           "Strict standards",
           // E_DEPRECATED, E_USER_DEPRECATED (since PHP 5.3.0)
           "Deprecated",
           // 0
           "Xdebug",
           // default
           "Unknown error"
       ],

       // Always close debug windows and restore layout on session stop.
       "close_on_stop": false,

       // Do not show possible password values in context output.
       "hide_password": false,

       // Show in output parsed response instead of raw XML.
       "pretty_output": false,

       // Always launch browser on session start/stop.
       // Note: This will only work if you have the 'url' setting configured.
       "launch_browser": false,

       // When launching browser on session stop do not execute script.
       // By using parameter XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP_NO_EXEC instead of XDEBUG_SESSION_STOP.
       "browser_no_execute": false,

       // Do not use the debugging window layout.
       "disable_layout": false,

       // Window layout that is being used when debugging.
       "debug_layout" : {
           "cols": [0.0, 0.5, 1.0],
           "rows": [0.0, 0.7, 1.0],
           "cells": [[0, 0, 2, 1], [0, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2]]
       },

       // Group and index positions for debug views.
       "breakpoint_group": 2,
       "breakpoint_index": 1,
       "context_group": 1,
       "context_index": 0,
       "stack_group": 2,
       "stack_index": 0,
       "watch_group": 1,
       "watch_index": 1,

       // Custom gutter icons for indicating current line or enabled/disabled breakpoints.
       //
       // Do not use same icon for following values, because Sublime Text is unable
       // to use the same icon for different scopes, in case there are duplicate icons
       // detected it will fall back to the corresponding icon in the package.
       "breakpoint_enabled": "circle",
       "breakpoint_disabled": "dot",
       "breakpoint_current": "",
       "current_line": "bookmark",

       // Path to Python installation on your system.
       // Which is being used to load missing modules.
       //
       // It is recommended to configure your Python path for Sublime Text 2
       // especially on older UNIX systems, where some modules (xml.parsers.expat)
       // might be missing and could improve performance of package.
       //
       // Example:
       // "python_path" : "/usr/lib/python2.7"
       "python_path" : "",

       // Show detailed log information about communication
       // between debugger engine and Sublime Text.
       // Log can be found at Packages/User/Xdebug.log
       "debug": false
   }
   ```
8. I left the XDebug.sublime-settings file alone and just ran the debugger.
9. Went to `http://localhost:9000` (and nothing happened, it just kind of got stuck loading)

The script I want to debug is in /Users/wf/Desktop   (the file is xdebugTest.py)

How should I set up the url? (I tried `http://localhost:9000/Users/wf/Desktop/xdebugTest.py` and 404)

I'll appreciate any help setting up the debugging parameters.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were on Github to clone the source, you should have run across the [README](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/blob/master/README.md) which, surprisingly, contains important information regarding installing and setting up a working Xdebug system on your server. The first important piece of information you probably missed is that [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org) is an extension for PHP servers. It's understandable, you were probably in a hurry and wanted to get started no matter what. However, if you'd kept reading the (still aptly-named) README, you would have found links to the xdebug.org website for details on installing the extension on your server, then a comprehensive section entitled [Configuration](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/blob/master/README.md#configuration) which guides the reader through each item in the `.sublime-settings` file, in addition to the thoughtful comments which are already provided. Finally, there is a section called [Troubleshoot](https://github.com/martomo/SublimeTextXdebug/blob/master/README.md#troubleshoot) which leads you through starting a session, setting breakpoints and watch expressions, exception handling, customizing the layout, and more. All of which documentation should enable even a PHP developer to get this up and running. Hopefully the next time you're in a similar situation you'll check it out.

Comment: I read the read me, hence why I knew to look at port 9000 and to set the url in the settings doc. However, it didn't do anything which is why I asked.  As far as php, I figured the tutorials were just written for php, but the concepts would apply to any language.     On that note, is there a way to debug python (or anything) in sublime text?

Comment: I make heavy use of [IPython](http://ipython.org) both within and outside of Sublime. Install it and all its prereqs on your system, then get [SublimeREPL](https://sublime.wbond.net/SublimeREPL) and play around with it.